# If $x^2 + y^2 + Ax + By + C = 0 $. Find the condition on $A, B$ and $C$ such that this represents the equation of a circle.

Tags: calculus, inequality, analytic-geometry, circles, conic-sections

> If $x^2 + y^2 + Ax + By + C = 0 $. Find the condition on $A, B$ and $C$ such that this represents the equation of a circle.
>   Also find the center and radius of the circle.

Here's my solution, I'm not sure if it's correct or not (specifically the conditions on $A$, $B$ and $C$. I feel that my conditioning is invalid and that this may be some sort of triangle inequality case.

I grouped the $x^2$ and $Ax$ terms, and the $y^2$ and By terms together and equated them to -$C$. 
After completing the square I am left with the following expression:

$(x + A/2)^2 + (y + B/2)^2 = -C + A^2/4 - B^2/4$

Conditions on A,B and C:

****CORRECTION MADE (Redundant inequalities need not be included)****

$C < (A^2 + B^2)/4$

Radius of the circle is  $\sqrt{-C + A^2/4 + B^2/4}$

The center of the circle is $(-A/2, -B/2)$.

Correct?

Comment: Keep the $C > (A^2 + B^2)/ 4,$ the other two are redundant. Radius and center are fine.

Comment: In the first line, that should be $-C + A^2/4 + B^2/4$ (the last sign is changed from what you typed). The rest looks good. As Will Jagy said, just keep the restriction on C and ignore the others.

Comment: On second look, the redundant inequalities are actually a bit incorrect, they would need $|A|$ and $|B|$ anyway.  If you have some $V^2 > W^2,$ the correct thing to say is $|V| > |W|,$ you may drop absolute value signs only if you know the relevant quantity is non-negative.

Comment: The radius of the circle is right. The inequality $C\gt (A^2+B^2)/4$ is not, it should be $C\lt (A^2+B^2)/4$.

Answer (score 4):

Completing the square is the right thing to do. We get
$$(x + A/2)^2 + (y + B/2)^2 = -C + A^2/4 + B^2/4$$
(I have corrected a little typo in the post).

For a circle, we need to have the right-hand side positive, or if you admit degenerate circles, non-negative. The condition I would use is
$$\frac{A^2}{4}+\frac{B^2}{4}-C\gt 0,$$
or something equivalent to that, such as $A^2+B^2\gt 4C$. No other condition is needed. (Note that in the post, the inequality runs the wrong way.)

The centre is right. The radius is $\sqrt{\frac{A^2}{4}+\frac{B^2}{4}-C}$.

Answer (score 0):

Lets' solve for:
X^2 + y^2 + ax + by + c = 0

Step 1: Add -x^2 to both sides

ax + by + x^2 + y^2 + c + - x^2 = 0 + - x^2

ax + by + y^2 + c = - x^2

Step 2: Add - y^2 to both sides

ax + by + y^2 + c +  - y^2 = - x^2 + y^2

ax + by + c = - x^2 - y^2

Step 3: Add - by to both sides

ax + by + c + by = - x^2 - y^2 +  - by

ax + c = - by - x^2 - y^2

Step 4: Add - c to both sides

ax + c + - c = by - x^2 - y^2 +  - c

ax = - by - x^2 - y^2 - c

Step 5: Divide both sides by x.

ax/x = - by - x^2 - y^2 - c/ x

a = - by - x^2 - y^2 - c/x

Answer is:

a = - by - x^2 - y^2 - c/x

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is almost complete.

The only thing that you are missing is actually answer the question.

For the equation to represent a circle, is needed that the radius is positive. Keep it going from $ \sqrt{ -C +\frac{A^2}{4}+\frac{B^2}{4}}$, by simplifying it: $$\sqrt{\frac{A^2+B^2-4AC}{4}} >0 \Rightarrow $$
$$\Rightarrow A^2 + B^2 - 4AC > 0$$

So, the final answer is: the condition on A,B and C such that this represents the equation of a circle is that $ A^2 + B^2 - 4AC > 0$.